# Append character if word count more then 20

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle SQL and I want to append a string with a character - if the size of that string is longer than 20. How do I do that?

well my try is this.

```
SELECT 
DECODE(PKG_DESC, 
LENGTH(PKG_DESC) > 20, '...',
'UNKNOWN'
) 
FROM VW_LOGIN_INF;
```

but showing error

```
Error at Command Line:3 Column:22
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN LENGTH(sentence) > 50 THEN
     sentence || '...'
     WHEN LENGTH(sentence) > 20 THEN
     sentence || '.'
     ELSE
     sentence
END as sentence
FROM
YOURTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks @OracleUser This full filled my need..

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN LENGTH(PKG_DESC) > 50 THEN
     SUBSTR(PKG_DESC,0,INSTR(PKG_DESC,' ',1,10)) || '...'
     WHEN LENGTH(PKG_DESC) > 20 THEN
     SUBSTR(PKG_DESC,0,INSTR(PKG_DESC,' ',1,10)) || '.'
     ELSE
     PKG_DESC
END as PKG_DESC
FROM
VW_LOGIN_INF
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 SELECT decode(sentence || appstr, length(sentence) > 20, sentence) FROM TABLE
```